# working with java combobox want to only remove the selected item from M S Access record not whole record

Tags: java

i am working with java applet GUI application and want to do that when i press on delete button only that item which is selected in combobox is deleted from M S Access but my below code deleted whole record from  M S Access..

```
code i tried is:

 if(e.getSource()==btn_del)
    {
       try
                {


                    Connection con;

                    DriverManager.registerDriver(new sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver());

                    Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");

                    con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:dsnproj","","");

                    Statement s=con.createStatement();

                    String q="select * from trans_dest
                                 where                                    
                                 dest='"+cmb_dest.getSelectedItem()+"'";

                    ResultSet r=s.executeQuery(q);

                    while (r.next()) {


                        r1=r.getString(2);

                        System.out.println(r1);

                        r2=r.getString(3);

                        System.out.println(r2);

                        r3=r.getString(4);
                        System.out.println(r3);

                        r4=r.getString(5);
                        System.out.println(r4);

                        String qryd1,qryd2,qryd3,qryd4;

                        qryd1="DELETE route1 from trans_dest where route1='"+r1+"'";
                        qryd2="DELETE route2 from trans_dest where route2='"+r2+"'";
                        qryd3="DELETE route3 from trans_dest where route3='"+r3+"'";
                        qryd4="DELETE route4 from trans_dest where route4='"+r4+"'";

                       if(r1.equals(cmb_route.getSelectedItem()))

                        {

                            System.out.println("in 1st");
                           int executeUpdate= s.executeUpdate(qryd1);
                           System.out.println(executeUpdate);

                        }

                        else if(r2.equals(cmb_route.getSelectedItem()))

                        {

                            System.out.println("in 2nd");

                            int executeUpdate1 = s.executeUpdate(qryd2);
                            System.out.println(executeUpdate1);
                        }

                        else if(r3.equals(cmb_route.getSelectedItem()))

                        {

                            System.out.println("in 3rd");

                            int executeUpdate2 = s.executeUpdate(qryd3);
                            System.out.println(executeUpdate2);
                        }

                        else if(r4.equals(cmb_route.getSelectedItem()))

                        {

                            System.out.println("in 4th");

                            int executeUpdate3 = s.executeUpdate(qryd4);
                            System.out.println(executeUpdate3);
                        }


                 }




              Frame f=new Frame();

               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(f, "Deleted product Successfully... ");

              System.out.println("deleted...");
       }
```

}

there is no error but removes whole record from my database insted of only on field which i selected...

output is:

```
apple
banana
grapes
null
in 2nd
1
ResultSet is closed
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from my database insted of only on field which i selected..
```

this means you are expecting to delete only that selected row.

As per DELETE query query, this is not posible. DELETE query will entire record from table which the query satisfies the where condition.

```
qryd2="DELETE route2 from trans_dest where route2='"+r2+"'";
```

this will delete entire row from DB for that where condition satisfies.

EDIT:

If you want to delete value for column, you can set column value to null using `update query`.

I.e `UPDATE trans_dest SET route2= NULL where route2='"+r2+"'"`

Comment: i want to delete only that cell from database which contains combobox item not whole row...

Comment: see the EDIT in anwser, that will help you

Answer (score 0):

See this example maybe it will be useful .

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.sql.*;

public class ComboboxTest  extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
    JComboBox  combo ;
    JButton    del;
    public ComboboxTest(){
        combo = new JComboBox(new String[]{"Apple","Orange","Banana"});
        del = new JButton("DELETE");
        del.addActionListener(this);
        this.add(combo, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        this.add(del,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        this.setSize(300,200);
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(3);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        JButton b = (JButton)e.getSource();
        if(b == del) {
        String query = "update trans_dest set CellName='' where dest = "
            + "'"+combo.getSelectedItem().toString()+"'";
        try{

              Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver").newInstance();
              Connection c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:dsnproj","","");
              Statement s = c.createStatement();
              s.executeUpdate(query);
              System.out.println("Selected Item Removed .");
              s.close();

        }catch(Exception ex){
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
        }//end if

    }


    public static void main(String...args){
        new ComboboxTest();
    }
}
```

Comment: not working....it removes whole record..i want to jst remove that item from particular cell....

Comment: I know what you mean
you might use Update query 
See I edited my answer

Comment: thank u soooooo much ...it works...i tried to solved it from last one day...finally done it...thank uuu